# Update data in table1 where duplicates in table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables: Users and Results.
The usertable contains duplicate data which is reflected in the results table. The user below is created 3 times. I need to update the results table where UserId 2 and 3 to 1 so that all the results can be viewed on this user only.
This is easy if I have only have a few users and a few results for them, but in my case I have 500 duplicated users and 30000 results.

I am using SQL Server Express 2014

I will really appreciate any help with this!

**Edit: misstyped column names in resultTable. Im sorry if you got confused by it.**

```
UserTable    
UserId---Fname---LName

1-----Georg-----Smith    
2-----Georg-----Smith    
3-----Georg-----Smith    

ResultsTable

ResultId---UserRefId     
1-----1    
2-----2    
3-----3    
4-----1
```

I have manage to select duplicates from usertable, but i don't know how to proceed further.

```
    ;WITH T AS    
(    
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Fname + Lname) as Cnt    
  FROM TestDatabase.Users    
  )    
SELECT Id, Fname, Lname    
FROM T    
WHERE Cnt > 2
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Express 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with the cte. The `ROW_NUMBER()` function can be used to flag duplicate UserIds, then you can join the cte into the from clause of your update statement to find the UserIds you want to replace, and join again to find the UserIds you want to replace them with.

```
;WITH cteDedup AS(
  SELECT
    UserId
   ,FName
   ,LName
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FName, LName ORDER BY UserID ASC) AS row_num
  FROM UserTable
 )

 UPDATE rt
 SET UserId = original.UserId
 FROM ResultsTable rt
 JOIN cteDedup dupe
   ON rt.UserId = dupe.UserId
 JOIN cteDedup original
   ON dupe.FName = original.FName
   AND dupe.LName = original.LName
 WHERE dupe.row_num <> 1
   AND original.row_num = 1
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16734/4)

Comment: Incredible! This worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Hopefully this will also be useful to other people.

Comment: Just FYI this will not work properly if you have 2 people in the UserTable with the same first and last name. Could be a problem in bigger organizations.

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly? On my test database it seems to have worked fine.

Comment: What I mean is if you have 2 actual different people with the same name.

Comment: Aaahh yes of course. In our db this is not a problem, but if it was i could just do PARTITION BY Fname, Lname, Phone, Anyway, thanks again. This saved me alot of manual work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ResultTable` has 2 columns with the same `UserId` name. I changed the second to `UserId2` for the query below:

```
;WITH cte As
    (
        SELECT      R.UserId, R.UserId2,
                    MIN(U.UserId) OVER (PARTITION BY U.FName, U.LName) As OriginalUserId
        FROM        ResultTable     R
        INNER JOIN  UserTable       U       ON R.UserId = U.UserId
    )


UPDATE cte
    SET     UserId2 = OriginalUserId
```

Comment: Yes thanks for noticing. I have corrected it now. And thanks for answer. I will test as soon as I am home.

Answer (score 0):

A little tricky query looks like this:

```
;with t as (
select fname+lname name,id,
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by fname+lname order by id) rn
from #users
)
--for test purpose comment next 2 lines
update #results
set userid=t1.id
--and uncomment the next one
--select t.name,t.id,userid,res,t1.id id1--,(select top 1 id from t t1 where  t1.name=t.name and t.rn=1) id1
from t
inner join #results r on t.id=r.userid
inner join t t1 on t.name=t1.name and t1.rn=1
```

And then you can delete duplicate users

```
;with t as (
select name,id,
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by id) rn
from #users
)
delete t where rn>1
```